# Align parenthesis Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am having a lot of trouble alligning my parrenthesis perfectly in emacs.

What is happening now is the following:

```
if (
    f
    );
```

What I would like to happen is the following:

```
if (
    f
   );
```

or

```
if (
   f
   );
```

My Emacs is in Verilog mode.

Thanks in advance!!

George

Edited...

Or let's say this is what I have :

```
for (   
     int k = 1;
     k < 5;
     k ++
     );
```

and I would like to get the following

```
for (   
    int k = 1;
    k < 5;
    k ++
    );
```

Comment: the responsible variable the overides the `verilog-cexp-indent` is: Verilog Indent Lists, when it is set to nil you can control the indentation in a split block (without indentation in the for loop after the first statement at all) , and when it is set to not nil that four spaces indentation seem to be global.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your configuration file:

```
(custom-set-variables
'(verilog-cexp-indent 3))
```

it should give you:

```
if (
   f
   );
```

But this is just the variable for indenting a statement that is split across lines, so if that does not apply for other cases that you are wishing to customize, look at : 
`verilog-align-ifelse` `verilog-auto-delete-trailing-whitespace` `verilog-auto-lineup` `verilog-auto-newline` ``` verilog-case-indent``verilog-indent-level ``` and add to the above 'custom-set-variables'

more info [here](https://www.veripool.org/projects/verilog-mode/wiki/Verilog-mode-Help)

Comment: you can try customizing in the Verilog menu `costumize Verilog Mode`... choose the Verilog mode indent group, there you will have access to the variables and the possibility to apply and save using Easy Customization

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was able to customize it in that mode but I still can't figure out this parenthesis, it doesn't seem to me inside the indent tab

Comment: There are simply two variables for number of spaces to indent. It is not relative to the other lines but instead a simple count of spaces from the befinning of the line. One for Case statements, and one for Split statements.

Comment: I tried changing the one for line from 0, 1 ,3 and 6, and none of them worked.

Comment: I just tried all variables in the Easy Customize menu and it seems to work fine. make sure that you change `State` to change for current session and that the buffer affected is the one you are customizing.

Comment: are you refering to this variable: Verilog Cexp Indent: Hide Value 4
   State: SAVED and set.
   Indentation of Verilog statements split across lines.

Comment: yes, that's the one.. I wonder if there is something overriding the value.

Comment: Maybe.. but it's sticking to 1 space no matter what I do :(

Comment: What I realized what that was doing was changing the space of the line after my for loop, so lets say it was set to 3, my indentation would put me on the new line, 3 spaces after the for loop

Comment: could you, please, post the whole loop in your original question? not indented as well as what you expect.